# When I randomize the bank variable, bankMoney becomes NaN

Tags: javascript, random, var, nan

Pretty self explanitory like my other questions. The problem is that when the person doesn't choose a bank, the variable `bankMoney` becomes `NaN` upon the first time calling `payDay` When they don't choose, its supposed to randomize via my `random` function, but I don't think it is. could someone please tell me why and/or fix it?

Thanks in advance.

If anymore code is needed  ie: a function I missed, missing characters etc., just tell me.

Code snipets needed to understand/fix problem:

```
 function random(high,low) {
       return Math.floor((Math.random()*((high + 1) - low)) + low)
    }

function propertyIncome() {
    bankMoney = bankMoney + houseIncome
}
var job = "Part time"
    function round() {   
        bankMoney = Math.ceil(bankMoney * 100) / 100;
        pocketMoney = Math.ceil(pocketMoney * 100) / 100;
    }
    function intrest() {
        if(bankMoney > 0) {
            positiveIncome(0)
        }
        if(bankMoney < 0) {
            negativeIncome(0)
        }
        round()
    }
    var salary = 10000
    var bankMoney = 120000
    var bank = prompt("choice a bank. (Put in the number, not the name.) (You only get to do this once, so choose carefully.)     \n 1. A&A Positive income: 10% Negative income: 25%     \n2. B&C Positice income: 5% Negative income: 7%     \n3. Limburgdi International:  Positive income: 12.5% negative income: 30%     \n4.S&N Positive uncome: 2.5% Negative income: 5%")
    if(bank < 1) {
        bank = random(1,4)
    }
    if(bank > 4) {
        bank = random(1,4)
    }
    if(bank == 1) {
        function positiveIncome() {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.1)
        }
        function negativeIncome() {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.25)
        }
    }
    if(bank == 2) {
        function positiveIncome() {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.05)
        }
        function negativeIncome() {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.07)
        }
    }
    if(bank == 3) {
        function positiveIncome() {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.125)
        }
        function negativeIncome () {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.3)
        }
    }
    if(bank == 4) {
         function positiveIncome() {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.025)
        }
        function negativeIncome() {
            bankMoney = bankMoney + (bankMoney * 0.05)
        }
    }
    var withdrawl1 = prompt("How much would you like to withdrawl? MUST Be GREATER THAN 1 if not greater than one, it will randomize, and you may not like the outcome. \n(bank transactions are taxed 9%)")
    if(withdrawl1 < 1) {
        withdrawl1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*(bankMoney - 1)) +1)
    }
    var pocketMoney = withdrawl1 - withdrawl1 * 0.09
    bankMoney = bankMoney - withdrawl1
    var randomVariable3 = " Your pocket money is $"
    alert("Your new bank balance is $" +bankMoney +"\n" +randomVariable3 +pocketMoney)
    function payDay() {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + (salary - (salary * 0.05))
        intrest()
        propertyIncome()
        round()
        alert("You have been paid,and your bank account has been given intrest. your new bank balance is: $" +bankMoney)
    }
    var house = prompt("Pick a house. Put in the number, not the name. (property income is 10% with $0 tax.  \n1)Mansion: $800,000  \n2)RanchSyle: $250,000  \n3)TwoStory: $300,000  \n4)R.V.: $50,000")
    if(house == 1) {
        var houseIncome = 80000
        bankMoney = bankMoney - 800000
    }
    if(house == 2) {
       var houseIncome = 25000
       bankMoney = bankMoney - 250000
    }
    if(house == 3) {
        var houseIncome = 30000
        bankMoney = bankMoney - 300000
    }
    if(house == 4) {
        var houseIncome = 5000
        bankMoney = bankMoney - 5000
    }
    function propertyIncome() {
        bankMoney = bankMoney + houseIncome
    }
    payDay()
```

Comment: Did you notice that your `random` function does not include `high` and `low`?

Comment: I can't repro what you described: http://jsfiddle.net/1uqh0936/. I only get NaN if I don't select a house (and that's because `houseIncome` won't be defined). Maybe learn more about functions, so that you don't rely on globals? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: I'm using the globals so I can call the values changed inside the functions at a later time. Otherwise, I'd define them inside the function. Ill fix the house problem too, thanks for pointing it out!

and reread the random function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values returned from prompt are always strings, so make sure to coerce them to numbers, and coerce undefined or null values as well

number + undefined = NaN

Comment: Hmm, how did you find out that `houseIncome` is not defined? `propertyIncome` is called inside `payDay`, which is called *after* `houseIncome` was set.

Comment: I think I've found the problem...
btw, houseIncome is defined in propertyIncome, like Felix Kling said, propertyIncome is called inside payDay which is called after houseIncome was set.

If im correct, the error is actually that it doesn't scan for the string if the person doesn't define a bank, it leaves it as undefined, which never randomizes, which prevents positiveIncome, and negativeIncome from ever being defined. 
Then adding undefined to bankMoney yeilds NaN

gonna go test that now. I think I can use the Parse.float to fix this.

Comment: @FelixKling you're absolutely right, I was typing a number that was not a house value.

Comment: I got it fixed the bankMoney and houseIncome were never enforced into numbers, preventing them from being evaluated for randomizing.
parseFloat fixed everything.

Comment: @wyattbergeron1 glad you got it working. You can also use `Number()` instead of `parseFloat()`

Comment: Never thought of that, I always just used parseFloat because thats how I learned to do it.